# Is it possible to find out whether the code written in Eclipse editor is valid and disable/enable context menu button accordingly?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, dsl, xtext

I'm creating Eclipse plugin for my DSL, using Xtext and need to add context menu item for my editor (what I did already), but need to find out whether the code in editor is valid, if yes -> this menu item should be enabled, otherwise disabled. Is it somethow possible to check whether the whole code is valid and update the state of this context menu item accordingly ? 
I added this context menu item by adding this fragment to the plugin.xml file in .ui project in Xtext.

```
<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.menus">
        <menuContribution locationURI="popup:#TextEditorContext?after=additions">
            <command commandId="org.first.langu.ui.handler.InterpreterCommand" style="push">
                <enabledWhen checkEnabled="true">
                    <reference definitionId="org.first.langu.Program.XtextEditor.opened"/>
                </enabledWhen>
            </command>
        </menuContribution>
    </extension>
    <extension point="org.eclipse.ui.commands">
        <command id="org.first.langu.ui.handler.InterpreterCommand" name="Interpret Code"/>
    </extension>
    <extension point="org.eclipse.ui.handlers">
        <handler
                class="org.first.langu.ui.ProgramExecutableExtensionFactory:org.first.langu.ui.handler.InterpretCodeHandler"
                commandId="org.first.langu.ui.handler.InterpreterCommand"/>
    </extension>
```

Basically I need to check whether code in editor is valid, instead of if editor is just opened.

Comment: maybe you should have a look at the concept of property testers and test if the file has markers (would require to have a build run before). besides that your requirement does not make sense to me. is there a problem behind you try to solve

Comment: or is this about the editor. then you could check annotations in the property tester

Comment: checking if the editor has markers is enough for my case, but is there any way to run build automatically in code ? because I have problem when editor is just opened with some errors, and nothing has changed in the file the build is not run automatically even if there is Build automatically checked directly in eclipse.

Comment: i dont understand. the errors by the editor and by the build should be the same
=> why do you need to build something

Comment: when I close eclipse with opened editor with some errors and open it again and call XtextResource.getErrors() there are no errors in this list, even when I see markers in the Eclipse editor directly. but when I change something in code -> build is triggered and validation is executed, so after that there are errors in that list

Comment: if you dont validate in your resouce thing there wont be errors. i mean annotations or markers on the file backed by the editor. validation in editor and build have nothing todo with each other => i still need to understand your usecase

Comment: My purpose is simple. When the code has errors (that means some markers) the context menu item is disabled. When the code is valid it's enabled. Now I have implemented handler for handling click on this button in context menu (InterpretCodeHandler). In this handler is also method isEnabled() where I can define whether this button is enabled or not, but in current situation I need some Listener which would listen to changes in editor and look if there are some errors every time the file is saved -> then set the variable which represents enabled/disabled state to the corret state.

Comment: then you should have a look at the annotation model of the editor

Comment: see e.g. org.eclipse.xtext.ui.editor.XtextEditorErrorTickUpdater.getSeverity(XtextEditor)
that is the thing that adds the red x to the editor icon in the tab

Comment: Thanks a lot Christian! That helped. Even when there are no errors in XtextResource.getErrors() at start of the eclipse, the annotation model knows about existing markers. You can add it also as answer to this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the editors annotation model to find out if there are any errors.
see `org.eclipse.xtext.ui.editor.XtextEditorErrorTickUpdater.getSeverity(XtextEditor)`
for an example on how to retrieve and filter the annotations. that class is used to display the red `x` in the editor icon if there are errors